# Format number using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I have written a code to calculate number of votes. I am getting the output as 138405, 150000 etc.

I want these figures to be formatted like this 138,405.
How do I achieve this using pure javascript?

Comment: please upload your code

Comment: Hey I will check that post. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide what the convention is first. Do you want your commas to separate two digits, or three?

Let's imagine that it's 3, as per the usual convention.

- `1000` should become `1, 000`
- `10000` should become `10,000`
- `100000` should become `100,000`
- `1000000` should become `1,000,000`

The code to make that happen can be as trivial as:

```
function formatWithComma(interval, num) {
    const digits = String(num).split('').reverse();
    const output = [];

    digits.forEach(function (digit, index, digits) {
        output.push(digit);
        if ((index + 1) % interval === 0 && (index + 1) < digits.length) {
            output.push(',');
        }
    });

    return output.reverse().join('');
}
```

This function expects to be called with an interval at which commas will be inserted and a number, from which to build a formatted string.

- `formatWithComma(3, 12345) === "12,345"`
- `formatWithComma(2, 12345) === "1,23,45"`

You could take this one step further and use Javascript's [partial application mechanism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a format function with the first argument preloaded.

```
var format = formatWithComma.bind(this, 3);
```

After that, any calls to `format` will insert commas at every 3rd digit.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your browser targets you could use `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` which will format your numbers based on locale which you can specify. Examples are on the linked page below.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

For example:

```
var number = 123456.789;

console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-US'));
// → 123,456.789
```

If no locale is specified the users browser locale will be used.

Comment: Hey thankyou, I had used this but its not supported in safari.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this function. It works fine for me.

```
function addCommas(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```